# c++, Visual studio express getting strange pre-runtime errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am getting pre-runtime errors with this little bit of code in my .cpp file.

`iFileName` is highlighted and saying "Error: this declaration has no storage class or instance type."

The comma between `iFileName` and `iWidth` is saying "Error: expected a declaration"

The right parenthesis is saying "Error: expected a declaration"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include "BMPCanvas.h"
#include "Fractal.h"

using namespace std;

BMPCanvas(string iFileName, int iWidth, int iHeight){
    filename = iFileName;
    width = iWidth;
    height = iHeight;
}
```

Does anyone know why I would be getting there errors?

Comment: BMPCanvas::BMPCanvas ?

Comment: @willll When I do that, the errors go away, but `fileName` becomes "Error: identifier "fileName" is undefined"

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your constructor like this:

```
BMPCanvas::BMPCanvas (string iFileName, int iWidth, int iHeight)
```

Also, you should add a `#include <string>`.

Comment: That didn't help, besides, would namespace std cover strings? (no offense, I'm just new to c++)

Comment: @user2726232 no, there are different classes of std namespace in different files. You should include necessary files.

Comment: BMPCanvas is a constructor, so adding a name there wouldn't help

Comment: Then you need to define a class first!

Comment: The class is declared in "BMPCanvas.h", do I need to declare a class in a .cpp file?

Comment: @user2726232: You need to show us the code that causes the problem

Comment: You should explain your question more throughly! I edited my answer according to your comments.

Comment: I don't know how to explain more... I told you exactly what I'm being told by Visual Express and the code is in my question.

Comment: You posted the error that VE told you, but you did not explained it. Also, you posted the part of code that caused the error, but it would be better posting all the code related (imo).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to include `string` header. Without it, `string` is not recognized as type name and `string iFileName` is not recognized as a proper declaration. This is the reason for your "pre-runtime" error, as you called it.

Secondly,

```
BMPCanvas(string iFileName, int iWidth, int iHeight) {
```

is not a valid function declaration. Functions declarations in C++ have to specify return type. The only functions that are allowed to omit return types are constructors, destructors and conversion operators. Yours in none of that.

Comment: I do intend it to be a constructor, I've tried making it `BMPCanvas::BMPCanvas` if you look in the comments on the question. If it would be invalid for any other reason, please let me know why?

Comment: @user2726232: And what happened? Again, you have at least two errors in your code. You have to fix *both*. Fix them, then report back.

Comment: I added `#include <string>` to no avail. I don't know what the other problem according to you is. What is wrong with my constructor?

Comment: @user2726232: "The other problem" is that out-of-class constructor definition is supposed to use `BMPCanvas::BMPCanvas`, not just `BMPCanvas` as in your code. Also, what does "to no avail" mean in this case? Adding `#include <string>` will make the red highlighting to disappear.

Comment: No, `#include <string>` did nothing at all for the errors. When I put `BMPCanvas::BMPCanvas` my `fileName` becomes "Error: identifier "fileName" is undefined"

Comment: @user2726232: Excuse me, but you yourself stated in the comments (in response to Mooing Duck) that adding `#include <string>` made the errors "to go away". Now you are saying that it did "nothing at all." How are we supposed to interpret that? In any case, you have to do two things: add `#include <string>` and name your constructor `BMPCanvas::BMPCanvas`. Do it. If you still get the error about `fileName`, then the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Also, you are posting misleading fake information. The code you posted does not have `fileName` identifier in it. It only has `iFileName` and `filename`. Notice the difference? Yet your are claiming that you get errors about `fileName`. How is that possible? You need to pay attention to error messages: post *real* error messages and/or post *real* code.

Comment: "@willl" means I was responding to him, not mooring duck. The other part of the file was made by a professor, so I am going to take it up with her. Thank you for bearing with me here.

Comment: @AndrewT  I am terribly sorry that I capitalized an "n" by mistake.

Comment: @user2726232: Well, that most likely means that you also capitalized that `N` by mistake in your class definition in the header file  (which you are not showing  here). Here's the bottom line: class `BMPCanvas` does not have `filename` member. This is what the compiler is telling you. Go to the class definition and re-check your spelling and capitalization.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the string header.

```
#include <string.h>
```